# Why does my program return nothing?

Tags: java, return-value

I just started learning java and for some reason my program returns nothing when it compiles.

Goal:
Write a method called *printPowersOf2* that accepts a maximum number as an argument and prints each power of 2 from 20 (1) up to that maximum power, inclusive. For example, consider the following calls:

```
printPowersOf2(3);
printPowersOf2(10);
```

These calls should produce the following output:

```
1 2 4 8
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024
```

Problem can also be found from [here](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/practiceit/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+2nd+edition%2FChapter+3&problem=3-e2-printPowersOf2)

my code:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] Args){
      printPowersOf2(3);
      printPowersOf2(10);           
    }
    public static int printPowersOf2(int num){
      double b = Math.pow(2,num);
      int a = (int)b;
      return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does returns the value but this is not what you want. You would like to *print* it! You should print the values in a loop using:

```
System.out.printf("%d ", a);
```

instead of `return a`; The full function:

```
public static void printPowersOf2(int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print("%d ", Math.pow(2, i));
    }
    System.out.println(); // for the line break
}
```

No need for `double`s, as these numbers are perfect squares.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] Args){
      printPowersOf2(3);
      printPowersOf2(10);           
    }
    public static void printPowersOf2(int num){
      for(int i = 0; i <= num; ++i)
      {
          double b = Math.pow(2,num);
          System.out.print(b + " ");
      }
    }
}
```

You do not have to return anything. You have to print inside the function only.